# Calculating percentage for columns dynamically in R

Tags: r, dataframe, division

This is my data

```
No col1 col2 col3 Total
1   5    8    9     70
2   3    4    11    80
.   .    .    .     .
.   .    .    .     .
10  6    1    15    90
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
 No  col1  col2  col3  Total  p_col1 p_col2 p_col3
    1   5    8    9     70    (5/70) (8/70) (9/70)
    2   3    4    11    80    (3/80) (4/80) (11/80)
    .   .    .    .     .       .      .       .
    .   .    .    .     .       .      .       .  
    10  6    1    15    90      .      .       .
```

This is what I have tried

```
 DF1=read.csv("R/path/abc_5.csv")
 DF1 <- DF1[,c(1:6,12)]
 nop <- basename("R/path/abc_5.csv")
  m <- gregexpr("[0-9]", nop)
     nop <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(nop, m)))
     nop <- nop[length(nop)]
     DF2 <- DF1[,2:(nop+1)]
    cn <- colnames(DF1)[2:(nop+1)]
     cn_p <- paste("p_",cn)
     DF1$cn_p[1] <-  mapply("/", DF1$cn[1], DF1$Total)*100
```

I want to automate this for all columns inside a loop, so I just tested for one column first
But I'm not getting proper output
Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks!!!

Comment: you just need to `sapply(dt[c(-1, -ncol(dt))], function(i) i/dt[["Total"]])`; and then `cbind()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
DF1[paste0("p_", names(DF1)[2:4])] <- DF1[2:4]/DF1$Total
```

Comment: Much better than my solution!

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli  Thank you for the comments.

Comment: @akrun you made it very simple, I think I was unnecessarily trying to complicate it by using loop. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. You use `sapply` to feed rows which gets divided by the total. then you can use `names` to assign the names to the newly create columns.

```
xx=cbind(df,sapply(df[2:(ncol(df)-1)], function(x) x/df$Total))
names(xx)[(ncol(df)+1):(length(xx))]=paste('p_',names(xx)[(ncol(df)+1):(length(xx))], sep = '')
```

Comment: why a `apply()` inside?

Comment: yeah i understood that... please make the changes